# Set selected item in ComboBox by Code

Tags: java, combobox, zk

I want to selected the first item of a comboBox by code if the value list have only one item. I've tried this:

```
Comboitem item = new Comboitem();
for(Empresa e : empresasList){              
    item.setValue(e.getEmpId());
    item.setLabel(e.getEmpNombre());
    item.setParent(cb_empresa);
}
if(empresasList.size()==1){             
    idEmpresa = empresasList.get(0).getEmpId();
//cb_empresa.setSelectedIndex(0);
    cb_empresa.setSelectedItem(item);
}
```

But it does not work. I also tried the commented line:

```
//cb_empresa.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether the `item.setParent(cb_empresa);` has an immediately effect to the view.
You can try setting the index later, or after refresh the cb_empresa.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is buggy. you have to create as many Comboitems as empresasList.size(). I guess something like

```
for(Empresa e : empresasList){
    Comboitem item = new Comboitem();              
    item.setValue(e.getEmpId());
    item.setLabel(e.getEmpNombre());
    cb_empresa.appendItem(item);
}
if(cb_empresa.getItemCount()==1){             
    cb_empresa.setSelectedIndex(0);
}
```

Should work. However, there was a bug in ZK that the setSelectedIndex() had to be postponed, as [Aloong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218275/aloong) mentioned. As far as I remember, this bug has been fixed. If not, you can use Event.echoEvent() as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Empresa e : empresasList){
    Comboitem item = new Comboitem();              
    item.setValue(e.getEmpId());
    item.setLabel(e.getEmpNombre());
    cb_empresa.appendChild(item);
}
if(cb_empresa.getItemCount()==1){             
    cb_empresa.setSelectedIndex(0);
}
```